# Unable to import from Excel XLSX file

Tags: excel, ms-access, import

I have a MySQL database on a remote server. I have saved the contents of the database table as a CSV file. I have then imported that file as a worksheet into MS Excel and all is good. However, when I try to import the data from the MS Excel file as a table into an MS Access database (.accdb) using the "Import" function I get the following error:

> The wizard is unable to access information in the file world.xlsx.
>   Please check that the file exists and is in the correct format.

The file definitely exists and is in .xlsx format.

If I try to import the data from the .csv file into MS Access I get a different error message:

> Could not find installable ISAM

It would seem that I am doing something wrong but searching in Google and this site I cannot see what my error is. Both files are in a folder that is listed as a "trusted location" to prevent errors due to lack of permissions.

I would be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction as this has me well and truly stumped.

Many thanks

Tog Porter

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample .xlsx file that reproduces the error? Also, please [edit] your question to indicate the versions of Excel and Access you're using.

Comment: I cannot find the version @Gord Thompson but I pay Microsoft every year for office365 so it must be the latest one. I have uploaded the .xlsx file to: http://www.a1touristguide.net/world.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on a different PC and it worked OK, so it must have been something corrupt with my MS Office installation.

I completely uninstalled MS Office from my main PC and re-installed it, which fixed the problem.

Note: Using the repair function in Control Panel did NOT fix it, it had to be completely uninstalled.

Many thanks for your help and suggestions.

Tog